# shell script to copy files from Server A to Server B

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I am writing a shell script to copy different extension files from server A to server B but it is not working. I have used this but not working.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "copying from Log Folder"
cd /hosting/a/apache-tomcat-7.0.39/logs
echo "Started the transferring files from PROD to FTP server"
echo "transferring Started"
HOST=Xyz.a.com
USER=log
PASS=log
ftp -n $HOST << EOF
echo "connection success"
user $USER $PASS
echo "login success"
put File1_log.txt
echo "transferred success"
echo "renamed success"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
  echo "Success.log">>success.log
else 
echo "Error.log">>Error.log
bye
EOF
```

This part is not working properly.

Comment: There here-doc can only contain FTP commands, not shell commands. So you can't do things like `echo` or `if` in there.

Comment: oh k I am newbie here. can u tell me with a bit clarity !

Comment: you can execute local shell command in ftp by ! at the begginning so instead 'echo "connection successed"' you should use '!  echo "connection successed"' but I am not sure how to test result of a command

Comment: If you're trying to test whether the file was transferred successfully, I am not at all sure that testing the exit status of `ftp` will tell you. I strongly agree with using `rsync` instead as was suggested; if you absolutely must use FTP, consider writing a Perl script with the [`Net::FTP` module](http://perldoc.perl.org/Net/FTP.html), a Python script with [`ftplib`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html) or something similar.

Comment: there are wildly divergent features and error reporting among the many versions of ftp that are available. If you must use it, then you'll have to take the time to build small test cases to see what your current version of ftp does with each error condition you can think of. If you're luckly it will exit with `1` for failed connection, login, or non-existent file and possibly for failure to cleanly write a remote file. You'll have to experiment, and if you expect that this will ever be used in a different or new OS, will need to document your testing, to facilitate rewriting.

Comment: Just did a quick test with my current ftp. Couldn't get it to return 1. So you may need to capture output, and parse for known error messages. Also, there are numerous postings here on S.O. that have some detail about "more-than-just-basic" use of ftp. I agree with all the advice you're getting to use `rsync` if it a available. Tell your boss it's not best practice to use ftp.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have SSH access to the server, use `rsync`:

```
rsync File1_log.txt $HOST:
```